# Pass model in a view backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Hi I've this function in my router:

```
  home: function() {
 var attore= new Attore();
 var page = new ListPostView({
 model: this.attore
 });
    this.changePage(page);

  },
```

and the model Attore is:

```
var Attore = Backbone.Model.extend({

defaults: {
"nome":  "caesar salad",
"cognome": "ravioli"

},



});


 return Attore;
 });
```

but happens an error that tell me model is undefined in the view:

```
var ListPostView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "ul",
    id: "list",

    template: Handlebars.compile(template),

    initialize: function () {
        console.log(attore);
      this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
      $(this.el).empty();
      _.each(this.model.models, function (ad) {
        $(this.el).append(new SinglePostView({
          model: ad
        }).render().el);
      }, this);
      return this;
    }
  });

return ListPostView;

 });
```

Comment: Probably because you are trying to pass `this.attore` but you never assigned your model to your router. You probably meant to pass in the model directly. `var page = new ListPostView({
 model: attore
 });`

Comment: It's very strange this error

Comment: What's strange about it? Where are you getting the error? Did you try changing the line like I suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes I've tried your suggested code

Comment: It looks like you are trying to treat your model in your *ListPostView* as a collection...

Comment: Yes but console.log in initialize function in view tell me that model is undefined

Comment: Your console.log is trying to log *attore* and not `this.model`.

Comment: Oh yes you're right!Tnx so much

Comment: That might fix the error you are currently getting but I think you might want to take a glance at the documentation since it looks like you are confusing models and collections.